# UDF problem creating a function using 10^

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, compiler-errors, user-defined-functions

I am trying to create a user defined function.

I have created several before, however i have never had a repetitive formula that i have tried to create a UDF for that has a 10^ included in the formula

here is my code:

```
Function VISCOF(X)

VISCOF=10^(10^((X-23.097)/33.468))-0.8

End Function
```

the error that arises is from what use of "^"

a "Compile error: expected: end of statement" which occurs exactly after the ^

i was wondering how i get around this, i assume i am requiring several lines to build up the formula.

any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

problem is with 64-bit excel need to use "10 ^" so enter a space between the 10 and the power of